# Cannot connect to 127.0,0.1 - CF Server (ColdFusion 2016) suddenly stopped and will not re-start

Tags: coldfusion, server, localhost, firewall

I have been using ColdFusion 2016 for about 5 months without problem. Two days ago I suddenly could not access the built in server, receiving such messages as this in Opera:

- 127.0.0.1 refused to connect (Opera)
- ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (Chrome).

When trying to start the server in Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools>Services I get

- Error Code 2 (non Microsoft app)

I thought it could be a firewall issue, since when booting up I saw a message saying that another app (Akamai NetSession)  was being blocked and that Windows Firewall had made some changes. However on checking the firewall, ColdFusion Server is being allowed through (as are Opera Chrome, etc).

I tried to starting the CF server from a command prompt, but after navigating to the `\bin` directory, and typing `ColdFusion.exe start`, I got no message of any kind.

I am on port 8501 with the server (8500 was used by and old version of CF11) but have never had any running problems. I am using the built-in server.

I noted that the IIS start page appears on 127.0.0.1 when I checked the relevant options, so localhost is not completely disabled.

I am not an expert on server issues. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance for comments.

**UPDATE:**

The full logs are:

```
May 17, 2017 5:03:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\lib;C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\jintegra\bin;C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\jintegra\bin\international;C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\lib\oosdk\classes\win
May 17, 2017 5:03:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8501"]
May 17, 2017 5:03:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
May 17, 2017 5:03:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8016"]
May 17, 2017 5:03:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
May 17, 2017 5:03:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 17, 2017 5:03:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
May 17, 2017 5:03:31 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
05/17 17:03:32 INFO License Service: Flex 1.5 CF Edition enabled
05/17 17:03:32 INFO Starting Flex 1.5 CF Edition
May 17, 2017 5:03:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ColdFusionStartUpServlet: ColdFusion: Starting application services
May 17, 2017 5:03:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ColdFusionStartUpServlet: ColdFusion: VM version = 25.72-b15
May 17, 2017 17:03:33 PM Information [localhost-startStop-1] - Starting logging...
May 17, 2017 17:03:33 PM Information [localhost-startStop-1] - Starting license...
May 17, 2017 17:03:33 PM Information [localhost-startStop-1] - Developer Edition enabled
May 17, 2017 17:03:33 PM Information [localhost-startStop-1] - Starting crypto...
May 17, 2017 17:03:33 PM Information [localhost-startStop-1] - Installed JSafe JCE provider: Version 6.21 Crypto-J 6.2.1, EMC Corporation. JsafeJCE Security Provider (implements RSA, DSA, ECDSA, Diffie-Hellman, ECDH, AES, DES, Triple DES, DESX, RC2, RC4, RC5, PBE, MD2, MD5, RIPEMD160, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, HMAC-MD5, HMAC-RIPEMD160, HMAC-SHA1, HMAC-SHA224, HMAC-SHA256, HMAC-SHA384, HMAC-SHA512, HMACDRBG, HASHDRBG, CTRDRBG, FIPS186PRNG, SHA1PRNG, MD5PRNG; RFC 3394, RFC 5649 AES Key Wrap; X.509 CertificateFactory; PKCS12, PKCS15 KeyStore; X.509V1, PKIX, PKIX-SuiteB, PKIX-SuiteBTLS CertPathValidators; X.509V1, PKIX, PKIX-SuiteB, PKIX-SuiteBTLS CertPathBuilders; LDAP, Collection CertStores)
May 17, 2017 17:03:33 PM Information [localhost-startStop-1] - Starting security...
May 17, 2017 17:03:33 PM Error [localhost-startStop-1] - Unable to initialise Security service: coldfusion.server.ServiceException: [C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\lib\neo-security.xml]coldfusion.wddx.WddxDeserializationException: WDDX packet parse error at line 1, column 1. Content is not allowed in prolog..
coldfusion.server.ServiceException: [C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\lib\neo-security.xml]coldfusion.wddx.WddxDeserializationException: WDDX packet parse error at line 1, column 1. Content is not allowed in prolog..
        at coldfusion.security.SecurityManager.loadSecurity(SecurityManager.java:1418)
        at coldfusion.security.SecurityManager.load(SecurityManager.java:1375)
        at coldfusion.server.ServiceBase.start(ServiceBase.java:59)
        at coldfusion.security.SecurityManager.start(SecurityManager.java:1365)
        at coldfusion.server.CFService.setupSecurity(CFService.java:438)
        at coldfusion.server.CFService.start(CFService.java:560)
        at coldfusion.server.j2ee.CFStartUpServlet.startCFService(CFStartUpServlet.java:565)
        at coldfusion.server.j2ee.CFStartUpServlet.init(CFStartUpServlet.java:508)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at coldfusion.bootstrap.ClassloaderHelper.initServletClass(ClassloaderHelper.java:121)
        at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.init(BootstrapServlet.java:59)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5049)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5341)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
May 17, 2017 17:03:33 PM Error [localhost-startStop-1] - Unable to initialise CFStartupServlet:[C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\lib\neo-security.xml]coldfusion.wddx.WddxDeserializationException: WDDX packet parse error at line 1, column 1. Content is not allowed in prolog..
May 17, 2017 17:03:33 PM Information [localhost-startStop-1] - Shutting down servlet container...
```

Comment: First - turn Windows firewall OFF and try it. If it works then you have some work to do with the firewall. Next, look in the runtime/logs direcory for the ***out.log - it will have more specific info about your startup issue. hope this helps.

Comment: Turning off firewall didn't help, but I see in the logs:  Unable to initialise Security service  coldfusion.server.serviceException,,, WDX packet parse error at line1 column 1  Content is not allowed in prolog... at coldfusion.security.SecurityManager.loadsecurity(SecurityManager.java1418) and similar error messages referencing java 1375, java 59, etc. I am not sure how to fix this, but am looking at it now.

Comment: Sounds like one of the configuration xml files is corrupt. Check to see if there is a recent backup. These configuration files are in `/Application/ColdFusion2016/cfusionlib` and typically have a name of `neo-*.xml`. I would start with `neo-security.xml` and see if there is a nearby `neo-security.bak`

Comment: Strangely there is no neo-security.bak (only neo-security.xml). I tried restoring the previous versions of other java .xml files, which did have .bak versions, but this did not solve the issues. A full log is now in the original post.

Comment: What changes were made to the machine two days ago (updates, jvm changes, services, etcetera)?  Maybe you checked already, but ... a) Look at the timestamp of neo-security.xml. Was it modified recently? b) View the contents of that file. Any obvious issues like leading white space or missing/invalid wddx?

Comment: There was a Java update installed three days ago, and immediately after that I encountered the present problems. I copied an old version of neo-security.xml across to the relevant folder, and was then able to start the CF Server. However I could not open the CF Administrator, receiving an error "The DataSource file is not available". I then checked the neo-datasource.xml file and found this empty.

Comment: (cntd) There is a neo-datasource.bak, but this was similarly empty. Further checks showed that the neo-drivers.xml, neo-secureprofile.xml and neo-icon.xml were also empty (no .bak versions exist). neo-document.xml has content. Maybe I need to reinstall ColdFusion 2016.